# How do I center objects in xcode for a universal application

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, object, center

I have created an iPhone app that works just fine, and it launches to the iPad as well, but when everything resizes on the iPad, it sticks to the top left corner. this is an example of how i was lining up objects;

```
-(void)addComponents
{
    message = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 362, 500, 21)];
    message.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

My goal is to be able to center this object rather then tell it the distance from any sides, so no matter what screen size the device is, it will center from the edge.

Comment: "in Xcode" - did you mean "using the Cocoa Touch API"?

Comment: yeah, sorry I am not extremely experienced with the terms.

Comment: no worries - I fixed that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you click on the view controller and then click file inspecter on the right pane and tick auto-layout. This will let you have constraints to automatically make it a certain distance from the edges.

Comment: I dont actually have a view controller (nothing to visually represent the code at least) , I have created the app from pure code.